# Wifi 6 ax200 not working apparently as it should

Tags: internet, iwlwifi

I am totally a newbie with Ubuntu, and installed a few days ago. I am using Ubuntu 20.4 and the latest kernel 5.4.3. My laptop is X1 Extreme Gen 2.  The whole thing is very nice except the internet speed. It's speed significantly differs from my other devices. I am gonna attach a picture here so let's see if anyone has any clue/solution.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfEWi.png)

Comment: Please add to your question the information which Ubuntu version you are using and what device you installed it on.

Comment: Please add this information to your question. Use the "edit" button. Relevant information should be contained in the text of the question, not hidden in a comment.